# Unable to set value for xtype :hidden in ExtJS

Tags: extjs4

I want to set value for hidden parameter in ExtJs.
Below is the code:

```
{
    xtype: 'hidden',
    id: 'ADDRESS_COUNTRY_CODE',
    name: 'ADDRESS_COUNTRY_CODE',
    value: "US"
}
```

I specified `value="US"`, but this is not getting set. The value is going `null`.

Is there any other way to set the value?

Thanks for your responses

Comment: Your syntax is correct according to the docs for: [Hidden](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.form.field.Hidden). How are you testing to see that the value is going null?

Comment: Hi Kevin, I am passing form parameters to controller and found it is going null. On change of dropdown I am setting the value for this parameter and in that case value is going fine. By default value is not going succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

i bet you the problem is else where like an incorrectly set ID (remove the id) or a duplicate field with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
xtype: 'textfield',
hidden: true,                            
id: 'ADDRESS_COUNTRY_CODE',
name: 'ADDRESS_COUNTRY_CODE',
value: "US"
}
```